# Why do images increase in File Size, when opened in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, google-drive

I have a lot of images, stored on my Google Drive, where I was hoping to compress the images through Photoshop.  I intend to convert all images into the JPEG/JPG Format.

The way in which I access my Google Drive Folder is by heading to:

> Computer > Hard Drive > Users > User Profile > Google Drive.

When I check the image file size, on Google Drive as per above, the file sizes vary between 1MB to 2MB. If I then open the same image, in a piece of software such as 'Photoshop', the image file size increase to 15MB+. How can this be?

Comment: You are checking the file size of the image stored in the cloud or on your disk?  Because Google by default stores an optimized image unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Both.  I checked in the Cloud and on Disk.  I opened image in Photoshop, from the Cloud, and when to 'Save for Web', to see that the file was 15x larger.  How can this be?  Is it a case that as soon as the image leaves Google Drive, it is no longer optimised?

Comment: If you are using a browser, to the view the properties of a file stored on your Google account, then you are going to get the web optimized file.  If you download the file, to a desktop, you will get the original file.  However, I can't determine if that is what you are actually doing.  Clarify your question with screenshots.

Comment: Do you mean JPG or PSD or some other format?

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies.  I have amended my question.  Hopefully, my question is a little more clear.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue in PS 2018. When you say you want to convert to JPEG, what format is it in now? Also, are saying that the file size changes on disk as soon as you drag an image into PS and doing nothing else?